# Return first 'term' hit from each aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation

Using Elasticsearch aggregations, is it possible to return only the first hit from each aggregation? I have not found this functionality detailed in the Elastic docs.

```
{
took: 1,
timed_out: false,
_shards: {
  total: 5,
  successful: 5,
  failed: 0
},
hits: {
  total: 2,
  max_score: 0.7380617,
hits: [
  {},
  {}
]
}
}
```

I use top_hits aggregation to ensure that the first hit of each aggregation is the hit which is relevant, so it would be neat if I could return only the first hit of each aggregation in a separate list. Is this at all possible, or does it require looping through the aggregated query results programmatically?

Comment: What is the query you used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform an aggregation, you want to check the `aggregations` json in your result, not the `hits`. Since you already know [Top hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), be aware that it provides a `size` option, so just set it to `1` and you'll have one hit per bucket.

In this example I am aggregating by a field in my index called `catL1`, and `top-categories` is the name I chose to give to my aggregation:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "top-categories": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "catL1"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top-categories_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my result is:

```
{
    "took": 33,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1248280,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            ...
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "top-categories": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 217939,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "category1",
                    "doc_count": 412189,
                    "top-categories_hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 412189,
                            "max_score": 1,
                            "hits": [
                                ONLY_1_HIT
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
 {
                    "key": "category2",
                    "doc_count": 3000189,
                    "top-categories_hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 3000189,
                            "max_score": 1,
                            "hits": [
                                ONLY_1_HIT
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that there is a json called `aggregations`, it contains only one hit per bucket (I replaced the hits with a placeholder)

**EDIT:**
You may be also interested in the total `hits` of course, but I mean that `aggregations` is what you are looking for in the context of this question